# Product of intervals

Tags: arithmetic, interval-arithmetic

Consider $x_0 \le x \le x_1$ and $y_0 \le y \le y_1$ . I'm looking for a formula that indicates interval of $xy$ . For example if we have $-1\le x\le 2 $ , how we can understand interval of $x^2 - 2x$ without graphing it . I think if there is a general formula , it can be very helpful .

Comment: You are saying $x^2-2x\leq 0$, isn't?

Comment: It seems that you want the minimum and the maximum of the function $f(x)=x^2−2x$ on the interval [-1,2]. Is this right?

Comment: @miracle173 No , I'm looking for a way for multiplying intervals . For finding extremum , we can use derivative easily .

Comment: @MANMAID you define $S_A$, but then don't use it in your question. That does not make sense. And why do you want $xf(x)$? What is $f$?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear to me but you tagged it interval-arithmetic. Did you alread read the wiki article of this topic? Is this the topic you are asking for?

Comment: How do you understand interval when graphing it? Can you show us an example?

Comment: Okay , For example we have $1 \le x \le 3$ . Our purpose is finding interval of $x^2 - 2x$ . After graphing the function , we can easily find out $-1 \le x \le 3$ . My question is this : How we can understand that interval without graph and using $1 \le x \le 3$ , $-1 \le x-2 \le 1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia says:

> [Evaluating a function at each element of a subset X of the domain, produces a set called the **image** of X **under** or **through** the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)).

This image of a set $X$ under a function $f$ is usually written as $f(X)$ and is formally defined as

$$f(X)=\{f(x)|x\in X\}$$

So you want know the image of the interval $[-1,2]$ under the continuous function $x\to x^2-2x$ and the image of the rectangle $[x_0,x_1]\times [y_0,y_1]$ under the continuous function $(x,y)\to xy$.

Your phrase "interval of $x^2-2x$" is not used for this and may not be understood.

But it can be shown that

- [if a function is continuous then the image of a connected set under the function is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected)

and

- [the image of a compact subset under the function is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/proving-continuous-image-of-compact-sets-are-compact)

From this follows

- If $f:[a,b]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then the image of $[a,b]$ under $f$, $f([a,b])$, is an interval.
- If  $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then the image of $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ under $f$, $f([a,b]\times[c,d])$, is an interval.

If the image $f(X)$ of $X$ under $f$ is an interval then we have
$$f(X)=[\min(f(X)),\max(f(X))]$$

So to find the left and the right endpoint if the interval we have to find the minimum and the maximum of $f$ in $X$.

If f is a [differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) from $[a,b]$ we know that **its extremal values (= minimum or maximum values) are either on the endpoints $a$ or $b$ of the interval $X=[a,b]$ or at one of its local extremal points in the inner of $X$**. These points can be found by using the derivative.

So for $$f(x)=x^2-2x$$ we have $$f'(x)=2x-2$$ which is $0$ for $x=1$.

So 
$$\min(f[-1,2])=\min\{f(-1),f(0),f(2)\}=\min\{3,-1,0\}=-1$$ and
$$\max(f[-1,2])=\max\{f(-1),f(0),f(2)\}=\max\{3,-1,0\}=3$$

and therefore

$$f([-1,2])=[-1,3]$$

For the two dimensional differential function 
$$p(x,y)=xy$$
similar statements hold. But even without differential calculus one can show that

$$p([x_0,x_1]\times[y_0,y_1])=[\min\{x_0y_0,x_0y_1,x_1y_0,x_1y_1\},\max\{x_0y_0,x_0y_1,x_1y_0,x_1y_1\}]$$

Other functions can be found in this wiki article about [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) where intervals are used to find bounds for rounding errors in computations.