# Compactness relatively to open subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, such that $\phi(U)$ is open and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

> Let $K\subseteq \phi(U)$ be compact. Show that $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$

My try: for every open cover of $K$ by open sets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ we can extract a finite subcover. Because $\phi(U)$ is open this means that for every open cover of $K$ by open sets of $\phi(U)$ we can extract a finite subcover, so $K$ is a compact as a subspace of $\phi(U)$. Then, because $\phi: U \rightarrow \phi(U)$ is a homeomorphism, $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is compact as a subspace of $U$ which is itself open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Hence for every open cover of $\phi^{-1}(K)$ by sets open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contained in $U$. How do I check all the other covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem:**Continuous image of a compact set is compact.**  See the proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2699919/779382)

Since $\phi:U\to \phi(U)$ is a homeomorphism, hence $\phi^{-1}:\phi(U) \to U (\subseteq \mathbb{R})$ is also a continuous bijection . Hence $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $\mathbb R$ since you can look at $\phi^{-1}$ as a continouos function from $\phi(U) \to \mathbb R$

Comment: It is compact in $U$

Comment: .......and hence compact in $\mathbb R$ . I have edited as well . Now I think your doubt is clarified.  @warm_fish Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover of $K$. Then $\{U\cap W\mid W\in\mathcal{A}\}$ is an open cover of $K$ which consists of open subsets of $U$. By your argument, it has a finite subcover $\{U\cap W_i \mid i=1,2,\cdots, n\}$. Could you see that $\{W_1,\cdots, W_n\}$ is a desired open subcover of $K$?