# How to show a continuous function in the reals maps compact sets into compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

How would I go about proving a continuous function maps compact sets into compact sets for the reals? I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/proving-continuous-image-of-compact-sets-are-compact) question pointing me to the Intermediate Value Theorem wiki, but I am still confused. Other answers use topology terms and inverse images, but I don't have those defined yet in my course.

Comment: What's the concept of “compact” that you are working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Start with an open cover of the image, then using the fact that the function is continuous shows the preimage of that cover is open and covers the domain (i.e the compact set), therefore it has an open subcover. It should follow easily from there