# Regarding existence of continuous function which is onto

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am solving previous years problems in analysis/ topology of my institute and I am doubtful about this answer of this question. 
Question is - Can there exists a continuous function from [-1,1] to **R** ( Set of Real numbers) which is onto. 
I think there can exists as any interval  is equivalent ( cardinality wise)  to set of real numbers. 
But the answer is no. 
Please help.

Comment: Note:  equicardinality does not require a *continuous* function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A theorem in analysis states that a continuous function on a compact set (e.g. closed interval) is bounded and attains its minimum and maximum.  Because $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, such a function cannot map to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

One can show that the continuous image of a compact set is again compact, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226328/450140.
As $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact with the standard topology this proves that such map can not exist.